# Вытащить часть строки по шаблону

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь-пытаюсь, никак не могу подружиться с регулярными выражениями:

```
var str = "ONE=lorem-one-1; TWO=lorem-two-2; THREE=loremthree"
```

нужно вытащить `TWO=lorem-two-2`,причем нужная часть может находиться как спереди, в середине или в конце, также текст имеет именно такой формат (`текст_или_цифры-текст_или_цифры-цифры`).. желательно хотелось бы вытащить по группам..пытался так:

`str.match('TWO=(\w\d)-(\w\d)-(\d);?')`

но все безуспешно

Comment: вы поточнее опишите какую строку вам надо получить и из чего. а то не понятно что вы хотите получить.

Comment: >нужно вытащить TWO=lorem-two-2

Comment: Метод [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) не решит вашу задачу? Он разобьет вашу строку на массив с тремя элементами, если передать в качестве аргумента `; ` (с пробелом). Затем можно будет просто обратиться ко второму элементу массива или перебором пройтись по каждому элементу в поисках нужного.

Comment: @terron вот вот, в 90% случаев вообще можно без регулярок обойтись, поэтому нужно подробно описывать что тебе нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. метод [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) принимает в качестве параметра регулярное выражение
2. В приведенном выражении нужно указать, что цифр или букв может быть несколько, для этого можно использовать `+`

В итоге получится так:

```js
var str = "ONE=lorem-one-1; TWO=lorem-two-2; THREE=loremthree";
console.log(str.match(/TWO=([\w\d]+)-([\w\d]+)-(\d+);?/));
var str2 = "ONE=lorem-one-1; THREE=loremthree; TWO=lorem-two-2";
console.log(str2.match(/TWO=([\w\d]+)-([\w\d]+)-(\d+);?/));
var str3 = "TWO=lorem-two-2; ONE=lorem-one-1; THREE=loremthree";
console.log(str3.match(/TWO=([\w\d]+)-([\w\d]+)-(\d+);?/));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Как подсказывает [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586103/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83/586135?noredirect=1#comment783953_586135), регулярное выражение можно чуть упростить, так как `\d` входит в `\w`. В итоге получится так:

```js
var str = "ONE=lorem-one-1; TWO=lorem1-two-2; THREE=loremthree";
console.log(str.match(/TWO=(\w+)-(\w+)-(\d+);?/));
var str2 = "ONE=lorem-one-1; THREE=loremthree; TWO=lorem2-two-2";
console.log(str2.match(/TWO=(\w+)-(\w+)-(\d+);?/));
var str3 = "TWO=lorem3-two-2; ONE=lorem-one-1; THREE=loremthree";
console.log(str3.match(/TWO=(\w+)-(\w+)-(\d+);?/));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: NB: `[\w\d]` = `\w`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, цифры входят в `\w`? :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, `\w` находит цифры, буквы и знак подчёркивания. В JS, буквы и цифры только из набора символов ASCII.